# document.execCommand not working in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, firefox

I am trying to setup some bold, italic and underline buttons for my textarea, I am using this code to make the switch from normal to bold/italic/underline.

```
document.execCommand("bold", false, "");
```

It works perfect in Chrome, but in Firefox and ie it doesn't change the text to bold or anything and I cannot work out why?

Here is the full code:

```
<input name="new_shout_bold" type="button" class="new_shout_text_option" id="new_shout_bold" onclick='document.execCommand("bold", false, "");' value="B" alt="B" />

<input name="new_shout_italic" type="button" class="new_shout_text_option" onclick='document.execCommand("italic", false, "");' value="I" alt="I" style="font-style: italic;"/>

<input name="new_shout_underline" type="button" class="new_shout_text_option" onclick='document.execCommand("underline", false, "");' value="U" alt="U" style="text-decoration: underline;" />
```

Here is the textarea:

```
<div id="dash_new_shout_textarea" name="dash_new_shout_textarea" class="dash_new_shout_textarea" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the the buttons unselectable in IE by adding `unselectable="on"` to the HTML tag.

Comment: This works absolutely perfect in chrome, ie and firefox. One thing, is it possible in firefox to make the cursor constantly on the text, so when you go to click the bold button the cursor doesn't stop so you can carry on typing and not have to reclick again?

Comment: @Arken: Yes: call the `focus()` method of the contenteditable element. In your case, i.e. using event handler attributes, this means adding `document.getElementById("dash_new_shout_textarea").focus()` to the end of the `onclick` attribute value. http://jsfiddle.net/Nfx3r/1/

Answer (score 0):

I know this won't help too much, 
but this code works perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox

http://jsbin.com/iluXOGe/2/edit

Comment: What version of firefox are you using? Mine is version 26